# Data recovery from corrupt Ubuntu partition/directory 

Tags: linux, ubuntu, data-recovery

I have an Ubuntu installation that won't boot anymore. I asked my previous question about it here: [Is there a chkdsk equivalent available for Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/15916/ubuntu-chkdsk-equivalent)

Bolotov replied:

> As I see from your previous question you can boot Windows so you could use dskprobe from Windows XP Service Pack 2 Support Tools to make sure that fs type is correct ... but it's already correct fs type 7 is NTFS.  
>
> Message "The type of the filesystem is RAW. CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives." means that windows can't determine fs type for some reason. As we see fs type is correct.  
>
> To run Chkdsk on your Windows partition you can install Windows Recovery Console, boot in recovery console and check your disk.  
>
> After checking the disk you will gain access to you c:\ubuntu\disks. I think you can mount your linux partition (which is in file) as usual loop-back device:  
>
> mount -o loop [path to your linux-loopback-partition]  
>
> But you should mount windows patrition first.

So now I'd like to know:
Within the recovery console I will be issuing the commands "chkdsk -r" and then "mount -o loop [path to windows partition]" and then "mount -o loop c:\ubuntu\disks", correct? I do have a ("corrupt and unreadable") c:\ubuntu\disks directory so that appears to be the correct path to the linux partition; do you know the path to the windows partition? would that be just "c:\"?

Comment: I'm so confused. Is this a windows or linux "recovery console"? How are you running linux commands (mount) against your c:\ drive? How did you map your linux partitions to a directory in Windows and not a new drive letter?  The accepted answer to the linked question talks about using `fsck`, but you describe using `chkdsk`, the windows version (which can't run against linux filesystems).

Comment: You should explain your questions better. This question makes no sense without reading every other question you've ever asked.

Answer (score 1):

I had my Ubuntu drive corrupted one morning. I used the **partition editor in ubuntu live cd** to fix this. There is an option to **automatically fix a partition**. It worked, I was lucky. You can try this first. Your exact situation is not very clear though.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to mount your windows partition. Your windows partition is already mounted and in use. Your linux partition, on the other hand, is a virtual disk contained in a file within your windows partition.